# Increment columns value based on duplicity record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have a question on whether if I can avoid using a cursor.

I have a table with thousands of record like this:

```
   Date    | Name  | StateData | 
-----------+-------+-----------+  
22-10-2019 | Tom   | OPENED    |   
22-10-2019 | David | NULL      |
22-10-2019 | Tom   | NULL      |
22-10-2019 | Brand | CLOSED    |
22-10-2019 | Tom   | NULL      |
23-10-2019 | Brand | NULL      |
22-10-2019 | Brand | OPENED    |
22-10-2019 | Tom   | OPENED    |
22-10-2019 | Brand | OPENED    |
22-10-2019 | Tom   | CLOSED    |
22-10-2019 | Brand | CLOSED    |
```

What I'd like to achieve is a result, where I can see each name on just 1 row with counting how many times they had which State "StateData".

```
      Date | Name | OPENED | CLOSED | UNUSED |
-----------+------+--------+--------+--------+
22-10-2019 | Tom  |   2    |    1   |    2   |
22-10-2019 | David|   0    |    0   |    1   |
22-10-2019 | Brand|   2    |    2   |    1   |
```

I've tried a select like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Name, d.[opened], d.[closed], d.[unused], StateData
FROM [dbo].[StateData] d

INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  DISTINCT Name, [opened], [closed], [unused]

        FROM [dbo].[StateData]
        GROUP BY  Name, [opened], [closed], [unused]

        ) dp
            ON dp.Name = d.Name 
;
```

I know it can be done with creating stored procedure using CURSOR, but I'm not that experienced with cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sql pivot](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/) as follows

```
;with cte as (select date,name,isnull(statedate,'unused') statedate from mytable)


select p.*  from cte 
pivot
(count(statedate) for statedate in ([Opened],[Closed], [unused]  )) as p
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    Date,
    Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN StateDAte = 'Opened' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Opened,
    SUM(CASE WHEN StateDAte = 'Closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Closed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN StateDAte IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Unused
from mytable
group by Date, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

GMB and Kemal,

thanks,

I have tried this

```
SELECT [Date],
       [Name],
       COUNT(CASE StateData WHEN 'OPENED' THEN 1 END) AS OPENED,
       COUNT(CASE StateData WHEN 'CLOSED' THEN 1 END) AS CLOSED,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN StateData IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS UNUSED
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Date],
         [Name];
```

but the result is not correct

```
Name  |  OPENED  |  CLOSED | UNUSED |
Tom   |  2       |   0     |  57412 |
Brad  |  2       |   0     |  57412 |
David |  2       |   0     |  57412 |
```

the correct result should be this

```
      Date | Name | OPENED | CLOSED | UNUSED |
-----------+------+--------+--------+--------+
22-10-2019 | Tom  |   2    |    1   |    2   |
22-10-2019 | David|   0    |    0   |    1   |
22-10-2019 | Brand|   2    |    2   |    1   |
```

but it seems like its just copy pasting the results.

Comment: You have written in the data thet you have  23-10-2019 | Brand | NULL

Comment: Is this an answer? Or a clarification of the question?

Comment: It was a clarification